# Close MySQL connection (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a class to create an automated connection with MySQL and create queries. Here's how it looks like:

```
include("constants.php");

class MySQLDB {
    var $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection);
        mysql_set_charset('utf8', $this->connection);
    }

    // SELECT ALL FROM
    function sf($unit, $table) {
        return mysql_query("SELECT ".$unit." FROM ".$table, $this->connection);
    }
        // and so on...
}

$mysql = new MySQLDB;
```

Now, I thought it would be better if I close the connection after I run some of this functions in other php pages. So how do I do that (the most effective way) in this class?

I tried adding `mysql_close($this->connection);` at the end of the class (before the close bracket) but it gives me an error.

Comment: Why do you have code after the return statement in `sf()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to place that code in a function named `__destruct()`, much in the same way as `__construct()`. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php for more information.

The code would then look like:

```
include("constants.php");

class MySQLDB {
    var $connection;
    var $sf;

    function __construct() {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection);
        mysql_set_charset('utf8', $this->connection);
    }

    // SELECT ALL FROM
    function sf($unit, $table) {
        return mysql_query("SELECT ".$unit." FROM ".$table, $this->connection);
        $this->sf();
    }
        // and so on...

    function __destruct() {
        mysql_close($this->connection);
    }
}
```

Please note that you don't know *exactly* when this method is run: that depends on when the object is garbage collected. But as Ken noted below, executing `mysql_close()` is good for symmetry, but not necessary to free resources.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't need this if you read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php) it says:

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.

If you still want to use it you need to but the function inside of the class...

```
      function close() {
          mysql_close($this->connection);
      }
          // and so on...
 }
$mysql = new MySQLDB;
```

Comment: Sorry fire - +1 since you beat me to it by seconds. Now I need to work out if I can remove my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [__destruct()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor) method add add that into your class and your close connection in there